# Laravel 4 cyrillic slug

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Currently in L4 you can't get slug from cyrillic string. In L3 there was an ascii array for that. Where and how can I add this array/ability to create a slug from cyrillic string?

EDIT

The library https://github.com/cocur/slugify is a good option, but I decided to use in L4 a custom Slug library from L3 methods and ascii array. Now I have in L4 working Slug maker just like in L3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install this library (https://github.com/cocur/slugify) via composer and use.

It's super easy to install and use.

Comment: Please explain how to install it?
I didn't find it easy at all.

Comment: Just add to your composer.json file, composer update and follow the repository instructions for use.

Comment: I think it's a good idea to also provide installation instructions for those who don't use Composer.

I couldn't make sense of it, so I've dropped it and used another piece of code that was simpler to use.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem when I was working with Arabic language, so I've made the following function which solved the problem for me.

```
function make_slug($string = null, $separator = "-") {
    if (is_null($string)) {
        return "";
    }

    // Remove spaces from the beginning and from the end of the string
    $string = trim($string);

    // Lower case everything 
    // using mb_strtolower() function is important for non-Latin UTF-8 string | more info: http://goo.gl/QL2tzK
    $string = mb_strtolower($string, "UTF-8");;

    // Make alphanumeric (removes all other characters)
    // this makes the string safe especially when used as a part of a URL
    // this keeps latin characters and arabic charactrs as well
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-ءاأإآؤئبتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهويةى]/u", "", $string);

    // Remove multiple dashes or whitespaces
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);

    // Convert whitespaces and underscore to the given separator
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", $separator, $string);

    return $string;
}
```

This function solves the problem only for Arabic language, if you want to solve the problem for Cyrillic or any other language, you need to add Cyrillic characters (or the other language's characters) beside or instead of these `ءاأإآؤئبتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهويةى` existing Arabic characters.